# Pygame loads images with RGB values offset 1px, but not alpha values

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pygame

When attempting to load an image via Pygames image load functionality, a black bar appears at the top of the loaded image. When slicing the tiles it became apparent that this bar offset the content by 1px.

Attempting various file formats (gif, png, alpha, non-alpha etc.) have similar effects with the offset, although notably png offsets everything except the alpha when using convert_alpha.

[Example of the offest, and random colours when split into tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr470.png), and the [the tileset image being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBxZk.gif).

Even a simple blit of the whole image has the same problem present:

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((128, 128))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

screen.blit(pygame.image.load("src/tiles.gif"), (16,16))
pygame.display.flip()
```

I have also attempted using `convert()` and `convert_alpha()`, both with similar effect.

Appreciate any help. I am running Pygame 1.9.1 in Python 3.5 on OS X 10.11.

Edit: I have tested it on both retina and non-retina displays, and it is the same on both. When using alpha it appears only the rgb values are shifted down 1px while the alpha remains in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set image alpha:

```
pygame.image.load("src/tiles.gif"), (16,16)).convert_alpha ()
```

Comment: I always use convert_alpha() but what is it do actually can you explain a little bit?

Comment: @ihsancemil convert() is used to convert the pygame.Surface to the same pixel format as the one you use for final display, convert_alpha () is for images that has trasparent pixels

Comment: Unfortunately I have been doing that, as well as just convert(). Both have the same effect.